# Locking the selection

Tags: modeling

I'm not sure that I'm using the right terminology but in other programs, once you have made a selection and it is highlighted  you can *lock* that selection and prevent it from being changed while you're doing other functions.

Is there anything similar in Blender?

Thanks

Comment: but depends in what kind of situation are you, so can you describe more your problem with images of the object/mesh?

Comment: if you don't want an object to be moved or rotated, you can do it in the Properties panel > Object > Transform Locks, but I'm not sure it's what you want

Comment: Maybe you could store the selection in a Vertex Group?

Comment: I would like to lock the selection in both the editing and object mode.

Your right maybe I'm not thinking this through from the perspective of a Blender user

Comment: Thanks to all that have answered you have given me a few good  ideas to look into :-)